# Remove extra space generated by a LaTeX command

Tags: etoolbox, csname, robust-commands

My LaTeX document contains the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{%
  \ifcsname spec@#1\endcsname
    \csuse{spec@#1}
  \else
    \GenericError{}{Undefined species `#1'}{}{}
  \fi
}
\defineSpecies{h216o}{H$_2^{~16}$O}

\begin{document}
\spec{h216o}. \spec{h216o} molecule
\end{document}
```

When compiling this document, an extra space (denoted with a red box) is put before the dot
in the PDF file:

[image]

Could you please help me to redefine `\spec{}` that
(a) it does not provide the red space before the dot, but
(b) it includes the blue space before the world *molecule*.

Please focus on repairing this command instead of suggesting packages, like `mchem`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `%` at the end of the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{%
    \ifcsname spec@#1\endcsname
    \csuse{spec@#1}% <<<<
    \else
    \GenericError{}{Undefined species `#1'}{}{}% <<<<
    \fi
}
\defineSpecies{h216o}{H$_2^{~16}$O}

\begin{document}
    \spec{h216o}. \spec{h216o} molecule
\end{document}
```

[image: aaa]

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot! I'll accept this answer in 3 minutes (as soon as tex.stachexchange allows). ;)

Comment: you missed one in the error case

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the missing `%` to mask endlines, you might exploit the `chemformula` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{\ch{#2}}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{%
  \ifcsname spec@#1\endcsname
    \csuse{spec@#1}%
  \else
    \GenericError{}{Undefined species `#1'}{}{}%
  \fi
}
\defineSpecies{h216o}{H2\,{^{16}}O}
\defineSpecies{caco3}{CaCO3}

\begin{document}

\spec{h216o}. \spec{caco3} molecule

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible improvement is to use a “centralized” species definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_tobir_species_prop
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \chemformula_ch:nn { ne }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineSpecies}{m}
 {
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_tobir_species_prop { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\spec}{m}
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_tobir_species_prop { #1 }
   {
    \chemformula_ch:ne {} { \prop_item:Nn \g_tobir_species_prop { #1 } }
   }
   {
    \GenericError{}{Undefined~species~`#1'}{}{}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineSpecies{
  h216o = H2\,{^{16}}O,
  caco3 = CaCO3,
}

\begin{document}

\spec{h216o}. \spec{caco3} molecule

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be good reasons for you to use `etoolbox`, but to write chemical equations, you do not need it.  Like highly recommended *for the body* of questions/answers/comments on sibling [chemistry.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/), you may simply use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) ([entry CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem)) to yield, e.g.

[image]

with an easier to read MWE like

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}  % neither requirement for, no inhibitor of a compilation
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
Our water is labelled as $\ce{H2{}^{16}O}$. $\ce{CaCO3}$ then is added.
\end{document}
```

The explicit call for version 1, 2, or 3 yield output with perhaps slightly different kerning; for the problem presented in your question, this however is irrelevant.  To use `{}` past `H2` prevents `2` to be misunderstood as a mass number of oxygen instead of an atom multiplier of hydrogen; the manual explicitly mentions this assistance by the user to the usepackage.

In addition to the project's own documentations, chemistry.se showcases some peculiarities in a dedicated [FAQ](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/4722#4722), too.